# Increasing size of 3d surface plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[Picture of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOo9o.png)

This should really not be this difficult. I am plotting a 3d surface plot from an array. The code looks like this:

```
z = arr
y = np.arange(len(z))
x = np.arange(len(z[0]))

(x ,y) = np.meshgrid(x,y)

plt.figure(figsize=(100,100))

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_xlabel("Bonus to AC")
ax.set_ylabel("Current AC")
ax.set_zlabel("Reduction in Damage")

plt.show()
```

It does not matter if I set the fig size to 10,10 or 1000,1000, the image still shows up the same size.

What kind of works is adding subplots,

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
```

but this splits it up into one okay plot and one empty plot. Not sure how to use the subplots function.

Comment: how are you previewing the results ? are you drawing it to jupyter notebook ? or are you drawing it to a window on your screen .. through a GUI canvas maybe ? most likely your viewport is rescaling the image , also try `plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=300)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm previewing them in google colab. Adding DPI=300 does not change the results. Maybe it is being rescaled. How do I see the unscaled version?

Answer (score 0):

you are referencing `ax` from a different figure than the one produced by `plt.figure`

you should instead use `ax= fig.add_subplot` after you assign `fig= plt.figure` as follows.

```py
z = np.ones((100,100))
y = np.arange(len(z))
x = np.arange(len(z[0]))
(x ,y) = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z)
ax.set_xlabel("Bonus to AC")
ax.set_ylabel("Current AC")
ax.set_zlabel("Reduction in Damage")

plt.show()
```

note i just swapped the `z=np.ones((100,100))` in the first line so viewers can get this working.